# What would the ideal situation be that would cause you to be the most anonymous?

Tags: security, ip, javascript, tor, physical-security

Let's say you were going to hack into the governments most precious data, what security precautions can you think of that would make you the most anonymous? My idea of a max security situation would be using Tor with a VPN that you 100% trust not to log your information, in tails booted off of a usb that you destroy afterwards, connected to a public wifi network, and making sure your screen can't be seen by cameras or other people. Is there anything else that you can think of that would make you even more anonymous?

Comment: Please don’t attempt to hack the government.  You will be caught.  Anyone famous enough for hacking the government is famous due to the fact they were caught.

Comment: @ramhound Not so.  Last I looked Snowden was still at large.

Comment: Fine; Caught or identifed.

Answer (score 2):

This will offer a very high degree of security, but is not totally inpenetrable. It's also not a particularly viable platform for hacking as it only secures limited protocols and does not provide the tools commonly needed for hacking.

Instead of booting a USB, I would consider running in a VM. In that way you can obfusicate hardware markers if the connection is hacked back - for example this will change the Mac address, CPU type, memory size, USB ports.

A common gotcha is DNS.  Make sure DNS does not bypass your vpn/tor.

The next difficulty is anonymously acquiring your VPN. If you pay in person you can be seen, if paying online there is a trail. Bitcoin provides pseudoanonymity - but there is a permanant record of the transaction.

Then things get really complicated - avoiding timing attacks on your connection (which can unmask a VPN) and exfiltrate data. Also, exit nodes can be compromised.

Of-course, the mindset of someone who would post this question is a problem.  Actions have purposes and consequences. People talk, boast, hint, make mistakes - non-technical markers can damn you. Often the social engineering tricks used to hack in in the first place can come back to bite you.